# Display 100% wide images in the side margins of a fluid grid?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

As a slight departure from the full-page stretching background idea, I would like to make a layout with an image in each of the side margins which stretches itself to fill 100% of the margin's width. (because, while the full-page image may work fine for pictures of leaves or certain natural elements, a photo of humans resized in a similar way may result in chopped off faces where they intersect the content area.  I would rather have each side resize independently.)

I played a little with trying to make it work in jsfiddle, but I need something a little more precise I think.

I am currently using the 960 grid (not fluid or responsive), and will be moving to Bootstrap 3's responsive layout shortly, so if either offers its own means for handling this question, that would be valuable too.

```
.left-image, .right-image{position:relative; width:30%;height:100px;
background-image:url("http://www.craftonhills.edu/~/media/Images/SBCCD/CHC/Layout/book-green.png"); background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% auto;
background-origin: content-box}

.left-image{border: 1px solid red; float:left}

.right-image{border: 1px solid green; float:right}

.content{width:200px; margin:0 auto; border: 1px solid black; height:100px;  position:relative}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5jBAJ/

Comment: I don't actually see a question here.  What exactly is the question?  What is not working?

Comment: You may have to stretch the width of the containing iframe to see what happens.  I should have clarified that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/ppollono/PUbBz/1/)

I think this is the solution for your problem

CSS

```
body{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 500px;
}
.wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 500px;    
}
.left-image, .right-image {
    position:relative;
    display: table-cell;
    height:100%;
    background-image:url("http://www.craftonhills.edu/~/media/Images/SBCCD/CHC/Layout/book-green.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-origin: content-box
}
.left-image {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.right-image {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.content {
    display: table-cell;    
    width:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height:100%;
    position:relative
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left-image">left image</div>
    <div class="content">Content goes here.</div>    
    <div class="right-image">right image</div>
</div>
```